# I can't open WhatsApp on HTC Windows Phone

Tags: whatsapp

I was asked to update the whatsapp and after the update, it never opened again.

I have uninstalled and downloaded a new one, but I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I had this problem before, with Messenger... it was a bug on the insider build. The temporary "solution" was to install Transparent Tile Pack, add and use the new icon..

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. It seems they have broken the app for Windows Phone 7.8 at least (i use a Lumia 800) with the latest update (2.16.64.0). I have already contacted the WhatsApp support (support@whatsapp.com). This is their answer:

> ### - WhatsApp Support -
>
> Hi,
>   Thanks for contacting WhatsApp. Your request has been received.
>   The solutions to most issues can be found by searching our FAQ. Please understand that we prioritize reports of issues with the application and provide a comprehensive FAQ to solve most other questions.
>   One thing we recommend is rebooting your phone (turning it off then on), which often times helps solve issues.
>   If you haven't done so already, please send us your phone number in full international format, including the country code. You can reply to this email to add an update.
>
> WhatsApp Support Team

I then sent them my phone number. Now I'm waiting for a response ....
Maybe if you contact them too, they will fix the problem earlier :)

Greets

EDIT: The latest update fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I can't reply to Martin's post cuz of no reputation. But I can confirm: I can't open WhatsApp with the latest update on my Lumia 800.